# Wrong distance in map

Tags: php, mysql, dictionary, distance

ok, i think i just fucked up everything because of my brain failure.

I followed Google's example of "phpsqlsearch_v3":

- imported the sql file
- change the query from showing miles to kilometers
- testing by using this:

  ```
  phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=37.315903&lng=-121.977928&radius=40
  ```

everything works as charm...

[image]

going into website to get latlong, adding and changing some data in db
now, I'm changing the `phpsqlsearch_genxml.php` to....

```
phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=59.627847&lng=17.838589&radius=40
```

...nothing... however, if i change radius to 8000 it will work but the distance for places  around input will be like 5665.231121242624km but if i flip the input because I'm on the right side of the earth *blink* *blink* to

```
phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=17.838589&lng=59.627847&radius=100
```

it will give me a more accurate result, however... the result should closer and around 1-2km...

suggestion what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAddress($lat, $lng) {
    $use_curl = false;
        if ($use_curl) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" . $lat . "," . $lng . "&sensor=true");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array (
            "Content-type: application/binary"
            ));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            if (curl_errno($ch))
            return -1;
            $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
            $str = substr($response, $header_size);
            curl_close($ch);
            $data = json_decode($str, true);
            if (isset($data["results"]) && is_array($data["results"])) {
            $street = $data["results"][0]["formatted_address"];
            $ac = $data["results"][0]["address_components"];
            $len = count($ac);
            $i = 0;
            $city = "";
            while ($i<$len) {
            if (in_array("locality", $ac[$i]["types"])) $city = $ac[$i]["long_name"];
            else if (in_array("country", $ac[$i]["types"])) $city .= ",".$ac[$i]["short_name"];
            $i++;
            }
            $meta = array(
            "status"=>200,
            "message"=>"Succeed."
            );
            return array("meta"=>$meta, "response"=>array("address"=>$street, "city"=>$city));
            } else {
            $meta = array(
            "status"=>406,
            "message"=>"Address is not known."
            );
            return array("meta", $meta);
            }
            } else {
            $str = @file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" . $lat . "," . $lng . "&sensor=true");
            $data = json_decode($str, true);
            if (isset($data["results"]) && is_array($data["results"])) {
            $street = $data["results"][0]["formatted_address"];
            $ac = $data["results"][0]["address_components"];
            $len = count($ac);
            $i = 0;
            $city = "";
            while ($i<$len) {
            if (in_array("locality", $ac[$i]["types"])) $city = $ac[$i]["long_name"];
            else if (in_array("country", $ac[$i]["types"])) $city .= ",".$ac[$i]["short_name"];
            $i++;
            }
            $meta = array(
            "status"=>200,
            "message"=>"Succeed."
            );
            return array("meta"=>$meta, "response"=>array("address"=>$street, "city"=>$city));
            } else {
            $meta = array(
            "status"=>406,
            "message"=>"Address is not known."
            );
            return array("meta"=>$meta);
        }
    }
}
```